# Spring MVC (text field and button) using CrudRepository and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I need to create a simple search button via a custom method using CrudRepository  and show the search results on a website.

**Event.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {
    private String name;
}
```

**EventRepository.java**

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>{
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name);
}
```

**EventService.java**

```
public interface EventService {
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name);
}
```

**EventServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

    @Override
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name) {
        return eventRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

**EventsController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/events", produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
public class EventsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEventsByName(@ModelAttribute Event event, @RequestParam (value = "search", required = false) String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("event", event);
        model.addAttribute("searchResult", eventService.findByName(name));

        return "events/index";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layouts/default}">
<head>
  <title>All events</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    <h3>Search for an event by name</h2>
    <form th:object="${event}" th:action="@{/events/search}" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" th:value="${search}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(search)}">
            <h2>Events search results</h2>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> Event</th>
                      <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Venue</th>
                      <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date</th>
                      <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="event: ${searchResult}">
                      <td th:text="${event.name}"><a href="/event/${event.name}">My Event</a></td>
                      <td th:text="${event.venue.getName()}">Event venue</td>
                      <td th:text="${{event.date}}">Event date</td>
                      <td th:text="${{event.time}}">Event time</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <h1>All events</h1>

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> Event</th>
          <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Venue</th>
          <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date</th>
          <th><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="e : ${events}">
          <td th:text="${e.name}">My Event</td>
          <td th:text="${e.venue.getName()}">Event venue</td>
          <td th:text="${{e.date}}">Event date</td>
          <td th:text="${{e.time}}">Event time</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using the naming convention for custom CrudRepository methods, which means that the implementation should be provided by the interface already.
When I run the web application and submit some input in the form, the desired html view is displayed, but the search result never shows any event.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqmJV.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaVnY.png)

I tried removing `@ModelAttribute Event` event and `model.addAttribute("event", event);` as in [this post which addresses the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314724/search-via-text-field-and-button-in-spring-mvc-crudrepository-thymeleaf) it was not used, but the outcome was the same.

I know that there is a similar post already, but the solution suggested there does not work for me and I tried different approaches but the result was not as expected.

Comment: Have you checked if your DAO is actually returning any results?

Comment: I think I found the problem: your div depends on the `search` variable, but you never set it. Try replacing it with `searchResult`

Comment: If you are addressing this line `<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(search)}">`, if I change search to searchResult it does not change the outcome. If I change `th:value="${search}"` to `th:value="${searchResult}"` I just get that weird "[]" in the text field  on Picture 2 in my initial post.

Comment: Also, I found out something really strange. I watched one youtube tutorial in which the author actually uses POST instead of GET method, but if I change the method to POST when I submit the form I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/sign-in, which is in the security folder despite the fact that I return "events/index" from my function in the controller. I think there is something wrong with the way I link the controller with the html page.

Comment: Search will get data, so it should use GET.  If you have to use POST to save data or something, then you have to handle the redirect on the client side, Ajax.onSuccess redirect window href to the new redirect.

Comment: It works successfully with GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventService.findByName(name);
```

Will look for exact name match

Create a new method for searching

**Service Interface**

```
public interface EventService {
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name);
    public Iterable<Event> searchForName(String name);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>{
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name);
    public Iterable<Event> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

    @Override
    public Iterable<Event> findByName(String name) {
        return eventRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Event> searchForName(String name) {
        return eventRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(name);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

When searching for nothing, do you want to display nothing or everything?  I prefer the latter.  If you want to not show anything, check for the search parameter before calling the service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showEventsByName(@RequestParam (value = "search", required = false) String name, Model model) {
    if(name!=null && !name.isEmpty()){
       model.addAttribute("searchResult", eventService.searchForName(name));
    } // else{ } create an empty list or handle null in view
    // ...
}
```

if you want to hide the table header if there are no results use

```
th:if="${searchResult !=null and !searchResult.isEmpty()}" <!-- For Both -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution, it worked! However, I first had to remove the if condition in my div block as it was preventing the html contents that it contains from being displayed. Everything works, but now if I submit an empty form it will display all the events as a result from the search.

Comment: I removed the thymeleaf conditional and checked if the string is empty in the controller, so it works.